# Using the same shortcode to show any table from the database

Tags: php, shortcode, wordpress

I have a little question for you.

I want to create a shortcode that makes a table with data that I have stored in a database. But i want to send the shortcode an attribute, to specify which table (database) I'd like to show.

```
add_shortcode("list", "list");

function list($tbl) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('item' => '')), $tbl);
    if($item!="") {
        $mydb= new wpdb('root','root','mydb','localhost');
        $rows = $mydb->get_results("select * from ".$item);
        echo "<table>";
        foreach ($rows as $obj) {
            echo "<tr>";
            //Here I want to put the content of the row
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>blank</h2>";
    }
}
```

The shortcode would be something like this:

```
[list item="table1"]
```

How can I use the same shortcode to show any table of a database? How can I manage each row to show all the fields it has got? Because i have different tables with different number of columns and different column names, and i want to display each cell in a  in the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it!

```
function list($tbl) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('item' => '')), $tbl);
    if($tbl["item"]!="") {
        $mydb= new wpdb('root','root','mydb','localhost');
        $rows = $mydb->get_results("select * from ".$tbl["item"].";",ARRAY_N);
        echo "<table>";
        for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for($j=0;$j<count($rows[$i]);$j++) {
                echo "<td>".$rows[$i][$j]."</td>";
            }           
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>blank attr</h2>";
    }
}
```

If someone has a better answer please share!

:D